# Application Web Site Design(Not WebView)

Tags: java, android

my question is; i wanna make a application for web site/forum/blogs view. I do not want to get the image and design directly ready. I want to change some parts of the site and edit the layout. As far as I know, webview method does not provide it this.

Which way should I follow way?
Thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing my best to understand the question.. From what I can gather, you would like to create an App that displays the content of a Website - but you would like to change what is displayed? I'm not sure that this is possible, without duplicating the Website yourself and changing the content as desired.. If this is *your own* Website though, this should be fairly simple, as you can create a hidden (un-indexed) 2nd version of the original contents, and then just properly format it for your App as you require.

Comment: So if I'm not the owner of the site, I can't change the appearance of that site on my application, right?

Comment: Correct.. If you display a specific Website address using webview, it's going to do exactly that - display the _exact_ contents of the Website. You can change the size of the webview and display specific parts of the Website (using it's anchor `#` points if available) - but the only other solution I can think of (assuming you don't own the Website) is to duplicate the contents yourself, adjust as needed and use it for your App.

Comment: Firstly thank you very much for your all answers.
"duplicate the contents yourself" can you explain this a little more?

Comment: If you need the _live_ contents of the parent Website, there may be ways to dynamically retrieve and display portions of it using your duplication site's code, but this would be completely outside the realm of _this_ topic, so it would be up to you to research that. As far as _this_ discussion goes, if I've answered your question to your liking, please _Accept_ the answer. Thanks, and good luck!

Comment: @rookie By "duplicate the contents yourself", I mean exactly that - create your own Website (so that you're the owner and can therefore edit it as desired), and simply replicate the website you're trying to adjust for your App, to your liking.. However I would highly recommend making this page a "hidden" page that isn't indexed, and set to no-follow, so it doesn't show up on search engines etc, as to avoid issues with the developer of the original. On that note, you still take the risk of issues since you're putting it on an App, so tread lightly and with caution. Good luck.